# Django API Query

Tags: django

I have a model called Mobiles with 2 Fields: Labels and Price

Im trying to find out how to pass the fields of this model to the view

and serialize them

---

serializers.py

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Mobiles
    fields = ['price']

class LabelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Mobiles
    fields = ['labels']
```

---

```
class ChartData(APIView):

def get(self,request,format=None):
    dataset = Mobiles.objects.all()
    serializer = DeviceSerializer(dataset,many=True)
    serializer2 = LabelSerializer(dataset,many=True)
    price = serializer.data 
    labels = serializer2.data  
    data = {
        "labels":labels,
        "price":price,
    }
    return Response(data)
```

---

This is what I get:

```
{
    "price": [
        {
            "price": 100
        },
        {
            "price": 101
        },
        {
            "price": 102
        }
    ],

 "labels": [
        {
            "labels": "A"
        },
        {
            "labels": "B"
        },
        {
            "labels": "C"
        }
    ]
}
```

---

But it should be like this :

---

```
{
    "price": [
        "100",
        "101",
        "102"
    ],
    "labels": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ]
}
```

---

Thank you for any help  !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
data = {
    "labels":[item["labels"] for item in labels],
    "price":[item["price"] for item in price],
}
```

But I can only warn you about the whole design - "parallel lists" (two or more lists matching on position) is a sure recipe for brittle code (if any of the list is changed in anyway, then the positions don't match anymore and your data are irremediably corrupted). A list of `{"label", "price"}` dicts is safer, and if the client code wants to build parallel lists, then it CAN do it from this list of dicts.

Comment: Thank you very much. Is there any documentation on how to do this?